# File iterator in ModelBuilder does not work correctly when passing variable input folder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

In ArcGIS ModelBuilder, I am trying to iterate over some ascii files (my_ascii.asc) in a folder (c:\my_folder) and converting them from ascii to raster. This works fine if I do it as shown below.

[image: working iterator]

however I want to pass some **parts** of the input folder as a model parameter.

So let's say my input folders are c:\my_folder_2010 and c:\my_folder_2030, i want the year to be a model parameter. If I make the year variable and pass it into the iterator like c:\my_folder_%year% as shown below, it does something weird. Iterator finds the correct files, outputs the correct 'name' ('my_ascii'), but the output ascii remains 'file.asc' instead of 'my_ascii.asc'. Once it enters the 'ascii to raster', it says that it cannot find the 'file.asc', which is correct, because it is called 'my_ascii.asc'.

[image: not working iterator]

Why does iterator only works correct for the 'name' part, and not for the 'file.asc'? Any solutions?

I also tried parsing a path into the first data element that goes into the iterator, but that also did not work.

Comment: Did you try giving the parent folder (the folder that contains folders 2030 and 2010 for example) and tick the recursive box? in that case you would not need to parse the path to each subfolder. This depends of course depends on whether all your data sits within the sub-folders of that parent folder, and that they are all organized similarly. (also make sure that the ascii files are not named the same in the different sub-folders

Comment: Have you investigated using the Parse Path tool?  If so, I think you should [edit] your question to be what happened when you tried that.